# Moving files to different folders via ssis if file exists

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an `ssis` package that loops through files and import the files to a SQL DB. In the loop the file is picked up regardless if it is a duplicate file. In my data flow i create a key that ignores the duplicates and imports new records.

After importing the file and ignoring duplicate i have a script task that check if the file exists in a destination folder.

```cs
string filepath; 
filepath = Dts.Variables["User::FILE_PATH_VAR"].Value.ToString();
Dts.Variables["User::FILE_EXISTS"].Value = File.Exists(filepath);
Dts.TaskResult = (int) ScriptResults.Success
```

Up to this point the package is working. What i want to do is, if the file exists in the destination folder move the file to a duplicate destination folder. If the file does not exist move it to the destination folder.

I have tried two file system tasks with *constraint editor* to the one on `File exist = true` and the `other = False`. But it only diverts to the one and moves both files to the duplicate folder.

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

[image: Image3]

Comment: Please provides snippets of the script you are talking about

Comment: Code used in script task. string filepath;
            filepath = Dts.Variables["User::FILE_PATH_VAR"].Value.ToString();
            Dts.Variables["User::FILE_EXISTS"].Value = File.Exists(filepath);
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;

Comment: Please, edit the question directly  instead of add comments next time.  I added it for you this time

Comment: Thanks. Apologies, i am new to Stack. I dont really do ETL via SSIS. I am more in the reporting side of stuff. How do i add screen shots?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28525/how-do-i-post-a-screenshot-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Maybe the `"User::FILE_PATH_VAR"` variable isn't pointing to the right file path.